# How to configure JAXB so it trims whitespaces when unmarshalling tag value?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How to configure JAXB unmarshaller so it will trim leading and trailing whitespaces from  strings?

For instance let's consider a simple binding between a Java bean and XML using JAXB annotations:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="bean")
class Bean {

  @XmlElement(required=true)
  String name;

  @XmlElement(required=true)
  int number;
}
```

I would like to be able to unmarshal XML given bellow so **bean.name** does not include starting and trailing whitespaces - is "**My name**", not "**\n    My name\n**  ".

```
<bean>
  <name>
    My name
  </name>
  <number>1</number>
</bean>
```

Comment: unfortunately XML parser treats that as "significant" whitespace if you can format your output without linebreaks would be easier than all the other hoops...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a custom *Adapter* class. I was thinking that [NormalizedStringAdapter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/NormalizedStringAdapter.html) would do the work but it's only for unmarshaling and it doesn't do what you want anyway.

```
public class MyNormalizedStringAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String marshal(String text) {
        return text.trim();
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return v.trim();
    }
}
```

then decorate the field with your adapter like this:

```
@XmlElement(required=true)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyNormalizedStringAdapter.class)
String name;
```

Comment: Is there any other way of achieving that without making a custom XmlAdapter?

Comment: Can it be that the NormalizedStringAdapter is totally broken?
It says that it removes leading and trailing whitespaces (see javadoc), but in fact it does not!

Comment: @Kutzi Yes, either the documentation or the implementation is wrong. All it does is replacing tab, lf and cr characters with a space.

Comment: Normalizing does not eliminate whitespace, only "normalizes" it, so the @kapep comment is describing the "correct" behavior, i.e. multiple consecutive "whitespace" characters are "normalized" into one space character.

Answer (score 4):

To remove leading and trailing whitespaces during unmarshalling you can use an adapter [CollapsedStringAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/CollapsedStringAdapter.html) (since Java 1.6).

> Built-in XmlAdapter to handle xs:token and its derived types. This
> adapter removes leading and trailing whitespaces, then truncate any
> sequnce of tab, CR, LF, and SP by a single whitespace character ' '.

```
@XmlElement(required=true)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
String name;
```

Comment: I tried this adapter but absolutely nothing happened when unmarshalling an XML file.Any ideas?

Comment: Did you use jaxb or something else? Maybe XStream?

Comment: Pure jaxb, exactly as described in this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/jaxb.

Comment: Mystic... It should work. Try to set annotations on getter.