# How to configure JAXB so it trims whitespaces by default

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, trim

I would like to configure JAXB so that it trims whitespaces on all string fields

I saw the following answer : [How to configure JAXB so it trims whitespaces when unmarshalling tag value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359315/how-to-configure-jaxb-so-it-trims-whitespaces-when-unmarshalling-tag-value)

But I do not want to have to annotate all string fields as per the suggested answer

```
@XmlElement(required=true)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyNormalizedStringAdapter.class)
String name;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

1. Create a [XmlAdapter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html).

   ```
   package com.foo.bar;
   public class StringTrimAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {
       @Override
       public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
           if (v == null)
               return null;
           return v.trim();
       }
       @Override
       public String marshal(String v) throws Exception {
           if (v == null)
               return null;
           return v.trim();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a `package-info.java` file in `com.foo.bar`.
3. Add the following to the `package-info.java` file

   ```
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=StringTrimAdapter.class,type=String.class)
   package com.foo.bar;
   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
   ```
4. This will apply `StringTrimAdapter` to **all** `String` fields in `com.foo.bar` without any extra annotations.

**EDIT**
Do note that if the package level annotation is too expansive for you, you could always apply a `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation to classes.

Comment: Nice answer - I can't speak to the content, but it's extremely well written.  I guess Blaise was out to lunch ;-)

Comment: @Ed Staub - :). Sahil beat me to it, I did +1 Sahils answer.

Comment: +1: This works well. See also [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16262197/521799) where Sahil's `XmlAdapter` implementation is used in a XJC bindings configuration.

Comment: See also the ready-made `CollapsedStringAdapter` at https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/CollapsedStringAdapter.html

Comment: @XmlJavaTypeAdapter is working fine if applies to fields but at class level its giving java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.Aclass field com.TLO.bfield to java.lang.String

Answer (score 9):

It might be worth mentioning, that in addition to writing an [`XmlAdapter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7420041/521799), which performs the trimming, you can configure XJC to actually use this adapter in generated code. An example of how to do it:

```xml
<jaxb:globalBindings>
    <xjc:javaType 
         name="java.lang.String" 
         xmlType="xs:string" 
         adapter="com.foo.bar.StringTrimAdapter"/>
</jaxb:globalBindings>
```

The above example uses the [`XmlAdapter` given in Sahil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7420041/521799)

Answer (score 0):

To make the example of configuring XJC `(in the answer provided by Lukas Eder)` complete, 
i would like to add the following sample configuration which we need to add in maven's pom.xml

```
    <build>
    .
    .
    <execution>
       <id>responseSchema</id>
       <goals>
          <goal>xjc</goal>
       </goals>
       <phase>generate-sources</phase>
       <configuration>
          <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
          <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
          <packageName>com.foo.bar.domain.response</packageName>
          <bindingFiles>../resources/bindings.xjb</bindingFiles>
          <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/xsd</schemaDirectory>
          <schemaFiles>response.xsd</schemaFiles>
          <extension>true</extension>
       </configuration>
    </execution>
    .
    .
 </build>
```

We need to have the following content to be added in  `bindings.xjb`.

```
<jaxb:globalBindings>
    <xjc:javaType 
         name="java.lang.String" 
         xmlType="xs:string" 
         adapter="com.foo.bar.StringTrimAdapter"/>
</jaxb:globalBindings>
```