# To remove unwanted space from xml

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd, jaxb

I have one .wsdl file which intereact with .xsd file generate some packages and class based on structure defined in .xsd file

and after that if i hit webservice request from sopUI which contain unwanted space.
Now i want to trim that space while unmarshalling for that i found one solution
[How to configure JAXB so it trims whitespaces by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419951/how-to-configure-jaxb-so-it-trims-whitespaces-by-default)

But i want generate package-info.java file automaticaly
Or suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday.

The best solution is to use

> @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)

. It is an existing built-in type adapter that can help you to trim the CDATA content.

for example, Lets take this XML

```
<books>
   <book>
      <name><![CDATA[ <br> Harry Potter </br>
        ]]></name>

   </book>
</books>
```

For this, You would have a Java class.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "books")
public class Books {

    @XmlValue
    protected String name;
    ......
}
```

You have to add that adapter *just above the variable name in which the CDATA part* is included.

```
@XmlValue
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
protected String name;
```

Then the IDE will ask you to import the required library files

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.CollapsedStringAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
```

Thats it. Hope it will help you:).