# Removing white space and new line while unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb

I want to unmarshal the xml, while unmarshalling i want to remove space or new line
and i tried with below example
[How to configure JAXB so it trims whitespaces when unmarshalling tag value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359315/how-to-configure-jaxb-so-it-trims-whitespaces-when-unmarshalling-tag-value)

But i cant put annotation on xml element 
because that class is auto generated

Please suggest me any solution regarding same or any other way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can try with JAXB bindings, this can be used to resolve things like classes generated with same name and other issues, just need to provide the details of the element you want to 'fix' . Here is some documentation about bindings

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html