# How to add XmlAdapter class via XSD file

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd, jaxb

I am new in XSD and JAXB.
I have an XSD schema file say logic.xsd, which generates one entire package, say "com.ilume" with some classes (Employee.java) and package-info.java file.

Now I want to add a custom adapter class in same package (adapter class like the `StringTrimAdapter` class shown in [How to configure JAXB so it trims whitespaces when unmarshalling tag value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359315/how-to-configure-jaxb-so-it-trims-whitespaces-when-unmarshalling-tag-value)).
This adapter class should generate from my logic.xsd (what should I add in logic.xml file so that it can generate that `StringTrimAdapter`?)

and I want `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyNormalizedStringAdapter.class)` added in package-info.java. What kind of binding I should write and where?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday.

The best solution is to use

> `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)`

.
It is an existing built-in type adapter that can help you to **trim the CDATA content**.

for example, Lets take this XML

```
<books>
   <book>
      <name><![CDATA[ <br> Harry Potter </br>
        ]]></name>

   </book>
</books>
```

For this, You would have a Java class.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "books")
public class Books {

    @XmlValue
    protected String name;
    ......
}
```

You have to add that adapter *just above the variable name in which the CDATA part is included*.

```
@XmlValue
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
protected String name;
```

Then the IDE will ask you to import the required library files

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.CollapsedStringAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
```

Thats it. Hope it will help you:).