# Trimming of spaces does not work in SOAP request

Tags: java, xsd, wsdl

The wsdl is top-down implemented. The java classes are generated using `cxf-codegen-plugin`.

It has a simple type defined as

```
<xsd:simpleType name="DescriptionType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="512" />
        <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
        <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

I tried to put `" description"` in the request but it does not trim the space. The "collapse" option should do that.

This is the wsdl:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wsdl:definitions name="foo"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.ec.eu/DataService/foo/V2.2"
    targetNamespace="http://xmlns.ec.eu/DataService/foo/V2.2"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
>
    <wsdl:import namespace="http://xmlns.ec.eu/DataService/foo/V2.2"
        location="fooAbstract.wsdl">
    </wsdl:import>

    <wsdl:binding name="fooSoapBinding" type="foo">
    
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        
        <wsdl:operation name="Insert">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:foo1Insert" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="ServiceFault">
                <soap:fault name="ServiceFault" use="literal" />
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="foo">
        <wsdl:port name="foo" binding="fooSoapBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://xmlns.ec.eu/DataService/foo/V2" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

And this is the Service implementation:

```
@Stateless
@WebService(portName = "foo",
        serviceName = "foo",
        targetNamespace = "http://xmlns.ec.eu/DataService/foo/V2.2",
        wsdlLocation = "/META-INF/resources/wsdl/DataService/foo/V2.2/fooConcrete.wsdl",
        endpointInterface = "foo.package")
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
@SchemaValidation(inbound = true, outbound = false, handler = SchemaValidationHandler.class)
@HandlerChain(file = "../../../../../../../META-INF/handler-chain.xml")
@DeclareRoles({READ_ROLE, WRITE_ROLE})
public class FooService implements Foo {
```

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen really? I though they were removed as it's explained here https://www.w3schools.com/XML/schema_facets.asp `The whiteSpace constraint is set to "collapse", which means that the XML processor WILL REMOVE all white space characters`

Comment: It seems that you're absolutely right. I'll remove my comment.

Comment: How does the generated code for the fields of `DescriptionType` look like? Are they plain strings or some other type? What are the annotations on the fields?

Comment: @Bogdan  Yes, a string. `@XmlElement(required = true) protected String description;`

Comment: I would have expected more annotations, something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359315/how-to-configure-jaxb-so-it-trims-whitespaces-when-unmarshalling-tag-value

Comment: Maybe I need to add extra arguments in the maven plugin? Currently I have none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `xs:token` type instead, does work.

It automatically removes white spaces and generates the following annotations:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "token")
```

https://www.w3schools.com/XML/schema_dtypes_string.asp

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/CollapsedStringAdapter.html